# Perform date and time calculation within subquery in insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Anyone able to suggest how I could insert the current date + rental period in one query? The syntax in the code block doesn't work but DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) works. I am trying to get the integer in INTERVAL to be based on the rental_period. I can do this with multiple queries but I am trying to do one (if possible).

```
INSERT INTO rental_details (rental_due_date, vg_id, rental_id) SELECT DATE_ADD( 
NOW(), INTERVAL rental_period DAY), vg_id, 1  FROM status INNER JOIN video_games as vg ON
vg.status_id = status.status_id WHERE vg_id = 3;
```

Thanks.

This works but I need current date + rental_period (rental_period is an integer representing the days to add to current date):

```
INSERT INTO rental_details (rental_due_date, vg_id, rental_id) select rental_period,
 vg_id, 1  from status inner join video_games as vg on vg.status_id = status.status_id 
where vg_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax appears to be correct. So, it is probably something about the data-type of your columns. You have not provided the details, but the following works:

```
create table vg_status 
( rental_period integer);

create table rental_details
(due_date date);

insert into vg_status values (3);

insert into vg_status values (300);

insert into rental_details 
select date_add(now(), interval rental_period day)
from vg_status

select *
from rental_details
```

You can see [the output in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfb74/1/0)